# Doubt in section 4.3 of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In section 4.3 (*Lagrange Interpolation*) of Hoffman and Kunze's *Linear Algebra*, 2nd edition, on page 126 after the proof of Theorem 3, the authors write

> From the results of the next section we shall obtain an altogether different proof of this theorem.

However, I cannot find another proof of Theorem 3 in the next section. Perhaps it is hidden in the results proved there, but I am not able to deduce any such proof from those results. Can someone help me find this different proof of Theorem 3?

---

The statement of the theorem in question is as follows:

***Theorem 3.*** If $F$ is a field containing an infinite number of distinct elements, the mapping $f \to f^\sim$ is an isomorphism of the algebra of polynomials over $F$ onto the algebra of polynomial functions over $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first proof is based on Lagrange's interpolation formula. But you can also prove the theorem by using this result on page 129:

> Corollary 2: A polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ over a field $F$ has at most $n$ roots in $F$.

**Proof**. Let $f$ and $g$ be two polynomials such that $f^\sim = g^\sim$. Setting $h = f - g$, one gets $h^\sim = (f-g)^\sim = f^\sim - g^\sim = 0$. In particular $h^\sim(x) = 0$ for all $x \in F$ and since $F$ is infinite, $f$ has infinitely many roots, and hence is the null polynomial.

Comment: After proving the above corollary, the authors state "The reader should observe that the main step in the proof of Theorem 3 follows immediately from this corollary." I somehow managed to miss this line completely. But thank you for the details!

Comment: You're welcome.